# VB.net loop mp3 until next IF is selected

Tags: vb.net, audio, media-player, mp3

Hey all i have the following code:

```
Dim totalDistance as Boolean = False

    If totalDistance <= 210 Then
        'red
        If isPlaying = False Then
            isPlaying = True
            WMP.URL = Application.StartupPath + "\red.mp3"
            WMP.controls.stop()
            WMP.controls.play()
            WMP.settings.setMode("loop", True)
        End If

        backupLineRED.Visible = True
        backupLineYELLOW.Visible = False
        backupLineGREEN.Visible = False
    ElseIf totalDistance > 210 And totalDistance <= 670 Then
        'yellow
        WMP.URL = Application.StartupPath + "\yellow.mp3"
        WMP.controls.play()
        backupLineRED.Visible = True
        backupLineYELLOW.Visible = True
        backupLineGREEN.Visible = False
    ElseIf totalDistance > 671 And totalDistance <= 1000 Then
        'green
        WMP.URL = Application.StartupPath + "\green.mp3"
        WMP.controls.play()
        backupLineRED.Visible = True
        backupLineYELLOW.Visible = True
        backupLineGREEN.Visible = True
    End If
```

I am wanting to loop the sound until it reaches the next IF statement. However i cant think of a way to check for it correctly because **isPlaying** would always stay *true* and i need to find a way to set it back to false when it goes into another IF statement.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Gotcha...maybe this will do what you need then:

```
    If totalDistance <= 210 Then
        'red
        If WMP.URL <> Application.StartupPath + "\red.mp3" Then
            WMP.URL = Application.StartupPath + "\red.mp3"
            WMP.controls.stop()
            WMP.controls.play()
            WMP.settings.setMode("loop", True)
        End If

        backupLineRED.Visible = True
        backupLineYELLOW.Visible = False
        backupLineGREEN.Visible = False
    ElseIf totalDistance > 210 And totalDistance <= 670 Then
        'yellow
        If WMP.URL <> Application.StartupPath + "\yellow.mp3" Then
            WMP.URL = Application.StartupPath + "\yellow.mp3"
            WMP.controls.stop()
            WMP.controls.play()
            WMP.settings.setMode("loop", True)
        End If

        backupLineRED.Visible = True
        backupLineYELLOW.Visible = True
        backupLineGREEN.Visible = False
    ElseIf totalDistance > 671 And totalDistance <= 1000 Then
        'green
        If WMP.URL <> Application.StartupPath + "\green.mp3" Then
            WMP.URL = Application.StartupPath + "\green.mp3"
            WMP.controls.stop()
            WMP.controls.play()
            WMP.settings.setMode("loop", True)
        End If

        backupLineRED.Visible = True
        backupLineYELLOW.Visible = True
        backupLineGREEN.Visible = True
    End If
```

Comment: Each **IF** statement needs to have a check since each .mp3 needs to loop until its in a different **if** statement.